# ExtensionDataObject showing up in service reference

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I'm writing a WCF service and the **ExtensionDataObject** shows up in my **Reference.cs** file of the service reference **even though I don't have it defined in my data class**.

I know what the ExtensionDataObject is for, but do not want to use it.

**I don't know why it's showing up**... **Can somebody tell me how to not include it in my service reference?** Additionally, there is an OptionalFieldAttribute which is declared in my service reference which again is not part of my data class. How can I remove this as well?

Here is the generated service reference declaration on my client:

```
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Runtime.Serialization", "4.0.0.0")]
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Name="User", Namespace="http://www.Ryder.com/SOA/DataContracts/2014/02/17")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    public partial class User : object, System.Runtime.Serialization.IExtensibleDataObject, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {

        [System.NonSerializedAttribute()]
        private System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject extensionDataField;

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.OptionalFieldAttribute()]
        private string PasswordField;

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.OptionalFieldAttribute()]
        private Ryder.ShopProcessService.Outbound.ShopProcessService.Permissions PermissionsField;

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.OptionalFieldAttribute()]
        private string UserIDField;

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.OptionalFieldAttribute()]
        private Ryder.ShopProcessService.Outbound.ShopProcessService.UserTypeEnum UserTypeField;

        [global::System.ComponentModel.BrowsableAttribute(false)]
        public System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject ExtensionData {
            get {
                return this.extensionDataField;
            }
            set {
                this.extensionDataField = value;
            }
        }

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
        public string Password {
            get {
                return this.PasswordField;
            }
            set {
                if ((object.ReferenceEquals(this.PasswordField, value) != true)) {
                    this.PasswordField = value;
                    this.RaisePropertyChanged("Password");
                }
            }
        }

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
        public Ryder.ShopProcessService.Outbound.ShopProcessService.Permissions Permissions {
            get {
                return this.PermissionsField;
            }
            set {
                if ((object.ReferenceEquals(this.PermissionsField, value) != true)) {
                    this.PermissionsField = value;
                    this.RaisePropertyChanged("Permissions");
                }
            }
        }

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
        public string UserID {
            get {
                return this.UserIDField;
            }
            set {
                if ((object.ReferenceEquals(this.UserIDField, value) != true)) {
                    this.UserIDField = value;
                    this.RaisePropertyChanged("UserID");
                }
            }
        }

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
        public Ryder.ShopProcessService.Outbound.ShopProcessService.UserTypeEnum UserType {
            get {
                return this.UserTypeField;
            }
            set {
                if ((this.UserTypeField.Equals(value) != true)) {
                    this.UserTypeField = value;
                    this.RaisePropertyChanged("UserType");
                }
            }
        }

        public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
            System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChanged = this.PropertyChanged;
            if ((propertyChanged != null)) {
                propertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the corresponding class declaration in my service project: Note that I just changed the namespace to "abc" for privacy...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace abc.Enterprise.DataTransferObjects
{
    [Serializable, DataContract(Name = "User", Namespace = "http://www.abc.com/SOA/DataContracts/2014/02/17")]
    public class User
    {
        private UserTypeEnum userType;

        private string userID;

        private string password;

        private Permissions permissions;




        public User()
        {
        }


        [DataMember(Name = "UserType")]
        public UserTypeEnum UserType
        {
            get
            {
                return userType;
            }
            set
            {
                userType = value;
            }
        }

        [DataMember(Name = "UserID")]
        public string UserID
        {
            get
            {
                return userID;
            }
            set
            {
                userID = value;
            }
        }

        [DataMember(Name = "Password")]
        public string Password
        {
            get
            {
                return password;
            }
            set
            {
                password = value;
            }
        }

        [DataMember(Name = "Permissions")]
        public Permissions Permissions
        {
            get
            {
                return permissions;
            }
            set
            {
                permissions = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can get rid of the `ExtensionDataObject` when the proxy is generated by Add Service Reference - it's most likely there as a safeguard.  As far as the optional fields, have you tried using automatic properties to remove the explicit backing fields?  Also, why are you using `XmlSerializer` *and* `DataContract`?

Comment: Ok, didn't know it always defaults by adding it in. As far as the automatic properties, I would have done that, but I'm taking over this project and all the classes (which are a lot) don't use them. I'm not going to waste time re-doing that one...